# Ndk build finished with non zero value 2

Tags: android-ndk

Well I was building an existing project where in I started getting this error -

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:ndkBuild'.

> Process 'command 'D:\Project\android-ndk-r12b/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

In Android studio, how to build the apk?

Here is the link for the files -

https://github.com/Petroula/Android-Car-duino

Comment: Why should you generate **jni/Android.mk** on the fly? The file in your case is stable. Put it in [app/src/main/jni](https://github.com/Petroula/Android-Car-duino/tree/master/app/src/main/jni) and you can run it from command line to see all the output easily.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex Cohn but can you give me a detailed step by step instructions for same. Being a beginner I have no idea of what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the closest to step-by-step instructions I can produce short of upgrading the whole project for you.

1. Remove all NDK-related stuff from the gradle files.
2. Follow the official [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html#ImportAProject) to import the existing project into latest Android Studio.
3. Follow the official [guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html) to add the existing native code to the modern Android Studio project you produced at step 2.